# Averaging every column in a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am currently using the following LINQ statement to pull certain data out of my DataTable

```
var possibleRows = _Data.Select("Distance > " + (location.Distance - delta) + " AND Distance < " + (location.Distance + delta));
```

I would like to end up with a DataRow that contains an average of every column that was in the select statement above without having to iterate through each column.  I have over 100 columns and all the data is numeric.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please specify which columns you currently have, valid input and output you expect to produce. Suppose your input row has string data, how would you handle it?

Comment: I have over 100 columns of double data.  I will change the question to reflect that.

Comment: You can just specify 3-5 columns and provide input/output for them, and then mention 95 columns like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do something like:

```
var rows = possibleRows.Cast<DataRow>();
var averages = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(col => new {
        Column = col,
        Average = rows.Average(row => (double)row[col])
    }).ToList();
```

Note this assumes `double` throughout.

Note this doesn't result in a `DataRow`; it results in a `List<>`, where each item in the list has the column and that column's average.

Comment: You don't know of a good way to end up with a DataRow output do you?

Comment: @PlTaylor well... why do you want a `DataRow`? You could always just change the end to `.Select(col => (object)rows.Average(row => (double)row[col]).ToArray()` and `.Add` that `object[]` to the existing table...

Comment: The biggest reason I want a datarow output is to keep my interface consistent with what is already in prod.

Comment: @PlTaylor I seem to recall that `table.Clone()` doesn't include the rows, so you could also simply clone the old table, and use add the results to the clone - then you have a table with exactly 1 row

Comment: I am running into a weird exception where it is struggling to cast the values to double even though I know they are.  I'm not even sure what info could be helpful here.

Comment: @PlTaylor if they won't cast to `double`: they aren't `double`. What are they really? could any be `DBNull`? could they be `float` / `decimal` / `int` / `long` / ...?

Comment: Hundred plus columns...I found one that somehow got imported as a string...import method(outside the scope of this question) fixed.